# Is my question suitable for the site?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have created a [mini game for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.android.gamex) and I want general feedback and suggestions for improvement. My idea is to keep the game a *mini* game and not add too much functionality.

The story is that the character is supposed to catch objects at different scenarios. [image] The purpose is the learn the Android publishing system and develop game logic and game engine. The repository is available at [my github](https://github.com/montao/gamex).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This site, like most every site in the Stack Exchange network, is intended for *specific, answerable* questions. That is, questions where one could reasonably expect that there is a "correct" answer (or, at least, answers can be judged as "correct" or "incorrect").

Asking for general feedback or suggestions about something, including projects you're working on, is not a suitable question for this site. You'd probably do best looking outside of Stack Exchange entirely, for something that is designed to facilitate discussions.